# Существует ли auto blur?

Tags: html, select, javascript

Необходимо чтобы при выборе в теге select какого-либо элемента, js обрабатывал событие. 
Сейчас делаю через blur, но для этого надо, чтобы пользователь еще после выбора сместил фокус в какую-нибудь область, что не очень красиво. 
Вот и  думаю, может есть какое-ниубдь свойство, которое при выборе селекта автоматически смещал фокус на другой элемент.

Comment: Может можно как-нибудь проверку js перед построением?
if ($('#cat').val()!='') $('#cat').val()='';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на jQuery, то очень просто:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert('Произошел выбор в select-е'); // меняем на смещение фокуса
})
```

На чистом js посложнее, почитайте [тут подробнее](http://learn.javascript.ru/events-change).

Comment: еще один  в накидку вопрос)
При выборе одного из селектов срабатывает js и появляются новые элементы в ДОМе. При перезагрузке страницы, выбор селекта сохраняется в кэше, и соответственно. js не срабатывает. 
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Выбор селекта сохраняется в кэше? Это как? При перезагрузке страницы обычно теряются все введенные значения, если вы не применили хитростей.

Comment: @Радик Камалов, вы принимаете ответ, потом снимаете только потому, что захотелось еще что-то спросить... Я бы на месте @Zhukov Roman, просто бы вас проигнорировал.

Comment: на-р пользователь отправил форму, и вернулся назад. firefox сохраняет последний выбор.

Comment: Если вы не можете отличить перезагрузку от действия "назад", то вам лучше начать... @Deonis, с чего ему лучше начать, подскажи? :)

Comment: нет. я принял ответ, .потому что принял. потом проверил оказывается не работает. потом проверил, оказывается я ступил не в том месте поменял blur на change. Потом проверил, все работает и опять принял ответ.

Comment: окей, как бороться, если пользователь нажал кнопку назад?

Comment: LocalStorage в помощь. Например, cохраняете туда индексы отмеченных checkbox.

Comment: с чем бороться? Что плохого в кнопке "назад"?